Basic ideas of discrete light-cone quantization for real scalar field
I'm trying to understand some basic ideas of discrete light-cone quantization. Based on this paper I studied, it seems to me that the basic idea is to first define the light-cone coordinates $$x^\pm = x^0\pm x^1,$$ then consider the real scalar field, we write the mode expansion in light cone coordinate as
$$
\phi(x^+, x^-) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dP^+}{\sqrt{4 \pi P^+}} \left( a(P^+) e^{-i P^+ x^-} + a^\dagger(P^+) e^{i P^+ x^-} \right),
$$
(or alternatively as a sum of $n$ from 1 up to some basis space cutoffs $K$). In order to get discretized momenta, we impose the periodic boundary condition so that $$\phi(x^+, x^-) = \phi(x^+, x^-+L).$$ By finding the conjugate momentum $P^+ = i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^-}$, we can set $P^+ = 2\pi n/L$. hence the momentum is quantized.
Is my understanding correct? Here $P^+$ refers to longitudinal momentum, is that right? Do we have some special properties of the Fock state obtained from the light-cone quantization, compared to otherwise (I heard there are some special properties on the vacuum state, but don't really know what that means)?
